# Date picker for selecting a period of time

Tags: android, datepicker

I need a custom date picker like [this](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker). But I need to select a period of time in my date picker. 
for example I want: user open the date picker dialog, then select start day, then select end day (days between this 2 days are highlighted) then close the date picker dialog.
is there any open source library which i can use for this scenario? 
or is there any way to edit [this date picker](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker) to achieve this ?

I will appreciate any help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use android [times square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square)

this widget supports date ranges, but not have the same look and feel

Comment: Times square is exactly what i was searching for. Thanks alot